# Parse webpage and save fetched images to a directory

Tags: beginner, ruby, parsing, interview-questions

I had a task for a programmer position which I failed. I am a newbie programmer and I accept that. The only problem is that employer never told me what the actual problem with the code is. So maybe community will be able to give few hints on how to improve it.

The task was to write code which would parse a given webpage, fetch all the images and save it to given directory. Webpage address and directory are command line parameters. Performance was a critical issue for this task.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

class Grab
    def runner(url, path)
        threads = []
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://#{url}"))
        img_srcs = doc.css('img').map{ |i| i['src'] }.uniq
        img_srcs = rel_to_abs(url, img_srcs)
        img_srcs.each do |img_src|
            threads << Thread.new(img_src) do
                name = img_src.match(/^http:\/\/.*\/(.*)$/)[1]
                image = fetch img_src
                save(image, name, path)
            end
        end
        threads.each{ |thread| thread.join }
    end

    def fetch(img_src)
        puts "Fetching #{img_src}\n"
        image = open(img_src)
    end

    def save(image, name, path)
        File.open("#{path}/#{name}", "wb"){ |file| file.write(image.read) }
    end

    def rel_to_abs(url, img_srcs)
        img_srcs.each_with_index do |img_src, index|
          img_srcs[index] = "http://#{url}/#{img_src}" unless   img_src.match(/http:\/\//)
        end
        img_srcs
    end
end
```

Comment: Most "newbie programmers" wouldn't be able to write the code that you did. You probably don't want to work for these people anyway! (Unless the job was something other than entry-level...)

Comment: Did the interviewer ask you to write code to accomplish the task, or simply get the task done? You could, for example, [use wget](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20116215/1157100) to get it done with one line of shell code.

Comment: This is awesome, tell those people to shove it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Few minor issues:

1. It will be cool if you support URL parameter with protocol (HTTP/HTTPS):

   ```
   doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://#{url}"))
   ```
2. For URL manipulations you can use standard tools - URI::HTTP/URI:HTTPS instead regexps:

   ```
   name = img_src.match(/^http:\/\/.*\/(.*)$/)
   img_srcs[index] = "http://#{url}/#{img_src}" unless   img_src.match(/http:\/\//)
   ```
3. This is a little unsecure operation, you should escape name:

   ```
   File.open("#{path}/#{name}", "wb")
   ```
4. You ignore links with HTTPS protocol:

   ```
   img_src.match(/http:\/\//)
   ```
5. This is not the Ruby way:

   ```
   img_srcs.each_with_index do |img_src, index|
     img_srcs[index] = "http://#{url}/#{img_src}" unless   img_src.match(/http:\/\//)
   end
   img_srcs
   ```

   A little simpler

   ```
   img_srcs.map do |src|
     src.match(/http:\/\//) ? "http://#{url}/#{src}" : src
   end
   ```
6. You load page uneffiсiently:

   ```
   image = open(img_src)
   ```

   So for every image temp file created.  This may not be an efficient way.

   ```
   open("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878891/how-to-load-a-web-page-and-search-for-a-word-in-ruby").class
   => Tempfile
   ```

Comment: I wouldn't call point 3 a minor security issue. It's an arbitrary file overwrite condition.

Answer (score 12):

IMO it's just rude that you took the time to write a code and got no feedback at all. Your code is not bad, but there's always room for improvement, hints:

1. make it more functional,
2. use specific libraries for the task,
3. return something useful for the main method (the saved file paths?),
4. use module URI to work with urls.

Anyway, given enough time and access to documentation, that's what I would have written:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'typhoeus'

class Spider
  def self.download_images(url, destination_path, options = {})
    base_url = URI.join(url, "/").to_s
    body = Typhoeus::Request.get(url).body
    imgs = Nokogiri::HTML(body).css("img")
    image_srcs = imgs.map { |img| img["src"] }.compact.uniq

    hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new(:max_concurrency => options[:max_concurrency] || 50)
    image_paths = image_srcs.map do |image_src|
      image_url = URI.join(base_url, image_src).to_s
      path = File.join(destination_path, File.basename(image_url))
      request = Typhoeus::Request.new(image_url)
      request.on_complete { |response| File.write(path, response.body) }
      hydra.queue(request)
      path
    end
    hydra.run
    image_paths
  end
end
```

Note: Images with the same file name will be overwritten, it has not been considered for simplicity. You'd just use `group_by` to add "-n" suffixes.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not familiar with Ruby, just a hint: If I'm right the code creates one thread for every `img` tag which could be too much. For example, the source of yahoo.com contains more than one hundred `img` tags which means 100+ threads and 100+ connections to the same host. You should use a thread pool with a queue which limits the number of parallel threads and parallel connections.

Furthermore, you should use [keep-alive connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) to download more than one image with one TCP connection. (I don't know whether Ruby supports it or not nor that the code above uses it or not.)

Comment: Just a quick note : the Ruby interpreter (at least the reference implementation) does not use system threads but so called "green threads". I think it's not really an issue to create a hundred threads. Your point holds for the http requests, though.

Answer (score 6):

Bit rude of them to leave you hanging.

Anyway, my 2c would be that the code is actually quite alright, but I'd argue, it's a basic web crawler and they've outlined that performance is a key goal, so half of the problem to solve would be to improve cache performance, i.e. to detect cache hits between runs (also to reduce effort of resuming from a crashed run.. in the event of a crash). This could be as simple as organising downloads correctly and checking for the existence of files (although you would need to be wary of only doing atomic writes for that to work).

Overall, could be a plethora of reasons to not hire, it's not always the code, so don't take it too hard.

Either way, if you are mainly concerned with feedback on the code, the main issues  that flag for me are:

### No error handling

I'd wager, if you failed based on code and not on solution flaws, it would probably be based on lack of error handling, or as below, maybe providing a comment about how x,y,z could fail. In this situation, you're dealing with threading, network and file IO, each of which is potential dynamite and should be well error handled if it's to be performant. (E.g. if a thread throws an exception, you could lose of all your work and have to start the crawl from the beginning again :( ) Ofcourse depending on the interview process, you may have been quizzed on such things, so it could be irrelevant.

### Lack of any commenting

Depending on how harsh you think they were judging you & the time constrains of the code (in interview vs do it and send), they may have expected you to provide commentary in your code.  It's probably not the biggest issue in interviews though from what I've seen.

Comment: I've worked at places that considered comments code smell. It was really painful to get comments laser code review so I stopped writing them. Unfortunately, this habit stuck :(

Answer (score 4):

I am not a ruby-developer either, but here are a few questions I have after reading your code,

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

class Grab
    def runner(url, path)
        threads = []
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://#{url}"))
```

I assume you are getting an array here

```
        img_srcs = doc.css('img').map{ |i| i['src'] }.uniq
```

The rel_to_abs method is odd. I think what you really need is a map .(explained why in that method)

```
        img_srcs = rel_to_abs(url, img_srcs)
```

Why did you choose to do the rel_to_abs outside, but extraction of name inside?

```
        img_srcs.each do |img_src|
            threads << Thread.new(img_src) do
```

What happens when the name extraction fails?
Also you assume that the name extracted is a valid file name. Is that always the case? (What happens if it is a query?) And I much rather prefer a smaller match like `.*\/([^\/]+)$`

```
                name = img_src.match(/^http:\/\/.*\/(.*)$/)[1]
```

Your fetch implementation feels like it is partly done. I would prefer fetch to either read the image or move the opening of uri completely to save. Right now, the resource (an open connection) is acquired in one method, and used in another, while you could have done both in one go, and avoided that. (I suppose there is nothing wrong in that, but it just feels wrong.)

```
                image = fetch img_src
                save(image, name, path)
```

If it were upto me, I would move the entire name processing and saving into a `save_to_disk(url,image-src,path)` and do the entire processing there. It would also have the advantage of not having to change a relative `mypath` to `http://domain/myapth` format, and then again extracting the `mypath`.

```
            end
        end
        threads.each{ |thread| thread.join }
    end

    def fetch(img_src)
        puts "Fetching #{img_src}\n"
```

Here, I would much rather see `open(src).read` so that the open connection is not exposed outside.

```
        image = open(img_src)
    end

    def save(image, name, path)
        File.open("#{path}/#{name}", "wb"){ |file| file.write(image.read) }
    end
```

This particular method feels rather odd. All you need is a map that checks if img_src matches http:// and if not, returns an updated version. Here you are mutating a data structure within a foreach loop (it works I agree) while you have no reason to do that.

```
    def rel_to_abs(url, img_srcs)
        img_srcs.map do |img_src|
          case img_src
          when /http:\/\// then img_src
          else "http://#{url}/#{img_src}" 
          end
         end
    end
end
```

And any reason you preferred to do the invocation in Grab.runner rather than Grab.initialize? with the later, you have to do `(Grab.new).runner(url,path)` instead of `Grab.new(url,path)`

But these are all minor. I wouldn't reject some one based on these. So I don't know.